Getting "item 9294277673006 no longer valid (was removed): object no longer valid" error in SAP Hybris
There is a process task in sap order process that deletes the existing order entries from the order and adds the entries from the sales order response that has line items as well. During the process, I'm getting this error while placing some of the orders:

item 9294277673006 no longer valid (was removed): object no longer valid

I suspect performing Modelservice.removeall and then accessing the same oldOrderEntries in the copyPricesForMatchingProducts is causing the issue. but I'm not sure how the stored entries are not accessible though the model service removed them that too only for few requests. Please help me on this.
public OrderModel convert(List<List<CPQInboundOrderLineItemDTO>> cpqInboundOrderLineItemDTOS, OrderModel orderModel) throws ConversionException {

    CatalogVersionModel catalogVersionOfProducts = null;
    List<AbstractOrderEntryModel> newOrderEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    List<AbstractOrderEntryModel> oldOrderEntries = orderModel.getEntries();

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(orderModel.getEntries())) {
        catalogVersionOfProducts = orderModel.getEntries().get(0).getProduct().getCatalogVersion();
        getModelService().removeAll(orderModel.getEntries());
    }
 for (List<CPQInboundOrderLineItemDTO> lineItemList : cpqInboundOrderLineItemDTOS) {
            for (CPQInboundOrderLineItemDTO lineItem : lineItemList) {
                OrderEntryModel orderEntryModel = getModelService().create(OrderEntryModel.class);
                                orderEntryModel.setEntryNumber(lineItem.getItemNumber());
                copyPricesForMatchingProducts(orderEntryModel, oldOrderEntries);

}


private void copyPricesForMatchingProducts(OrderEntryModel orderEntryModel, List<AbstractOrderEntryModel> oldOrderEntries) {

        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(oldOrderEntries)) {
            for (AbstractOrderEntryModel oldOrderEntryModel : oldOrderEntries) {
                if (oldOrderEntryModel.getProduct().getCode() == orderEntryModel.getProduct().getCode()) {
                    orderEntryModel.setBasePrice(oldOrderEntryModel.getBasePrice());
                   orderEntryModel.setSalesOrgCountryPrice(oldOrderEntryModel.getSalesOrgCountryPrice());
                    
                }

            }
        }
    }

Detailed error:

item 8975006367790 no longer valid (was removed): object no longer valid","thrown":{"commonElementCount":0,"localizedMessage":"item 8975006367790 no longer valid (was removed): object no longer valid","message":"item 8975006367790 no longer valid (was removed): object no longer valid","name":"de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloObjectNoLongerValidException","extendedStackTrace":[{"class":"de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item$CachedGetter","method":"get","file":"Item.java","line":740,"exact":false,"location":"coreserver.jar","version":"?"},{"class":"de.hybris.platform.jalo.ExtensibleItem","method":"getProperty","file":"ExtensibleItem.java","line":343,"exact":false,"location":"coreserver.jar","version":"?"},{"class":"de.hybris.platform.jalo.order.GeneratedAbstractOrderEntry","method":"getBasePrice","file":"GeneratedAbstractOrderEntry.java","line":106,"exact":false,"location":"coreserver.jar","version":"?"},{"class":"jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl","method":"invoke0","file":"NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java","line":-2,"exact":false,"location":"?","version":"?"},{"class":"jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl","method":"invoke","file":"NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java","line":77,"exact":false,"location":"?","version":"?"},{"class":"jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl","method":"invoke","file":"DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java","line":43,"exact":false,"location":"?","version":"?"},{"class":"java.lang.reflect.Method","method":"invoke","file":"Method.java","line":568,"exact":false,"location":"?","version":"?"},{"class":"de.hybris.platform.jalo.type.ReflectionAttributeAccess$AttributeMethod","method":"invokeGetter","file":"ReflectionAttributeAccess.java","line":753,"exact":false,"location":"coreserver.jar","version":"?"},{"class":"de.hybris.platform.jalo.type.ReflectionAttributeAccess","method":"getValue","file":"ReflectionAttributeAccess.java","line":959,"exact":false,"location":"coreserver.jar","version":"?"},{"class":"de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item","method":"getAttribute","file":"Item.java","line":1921,"exact":false,"location":"coreserver.jar","version":"?"},{"class":"de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.JaloPersistenceObject","method":"readRawValue","file":"JaloPersistenceObject.java","line":110,"exact":false,"location":"coreserver.jar","version":"?"},{"class":"de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.converter.impl.ItemModelConverter","method":"readSingleAttribute","file":"ItemModelConverter.java","line":1447,"exact":false,"location":"coreserver.jar","version":"?"},{"class":"de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.converter.impl.ItemAttributeProvider","method":"getAttribute","file":"ItemAttributeProvider.java","line":110,"exact":false,"location":"coreserver.jar","version":"?"},{"class":"de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl","method":"loadUnlocalizedAttribute","file":"ItemModelContextImpl.java","line":285,"exact":false,"location":"coreserver.jar","version":"?"},{"class":"de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl","method":"getValue","file":"ItemModelContextImpl.java","line":245,"exact":false,"location":"coreserver.jar","version":"?"},{"class":"de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl","method":"getPropertyValue","file":"ItemModelContextImpl.java","line":261,"exact":false,"location":"coreserver.jar","version":"?"},{"class":"de.hybris.platform.core.model.order.AbstractOrderEntryModel","method":"getBasePrice","file":"AbstractOrderEntryModel.java","line":262,"exact":false,"location":"models.jar","version":"?"},{"class":"com.octanner.pricing.converter.impl.CPQInboundOrderLineItemConverter","method":"copyPricesForMatchingProducts","file":"CPQInboundOrderLineItemConverter.java","line":93,"exact":false,"location":"octsegmentpricingserver.jar","version":"?"}


I assume that order creation logic try to access this item. You can try to commit and refresh after removing for your order object.
But this cannot be resolve  your issue if you have multiple node in production. Because cache sync doesn't fast. So you need to avoid removing items. Maybe also you need them for future investigation.
Best practice:

Create order another version and make changes on it.
Create cleanup job or use data retention framework to remove not needed data.

